# Scale and position in bitmap overlay

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I am working on a screen that allows user to drag and drop one image onto another. After that the code should be able to redisplay the resulting image. I am having a hard time making the reddit image normal size. More details about it is **in bold next to screen 3 below**.

Note: all of my images so far are in the res/drawable folder.

Screen 1: Initial screen:
[image: initial screen]

Screen 2: After the reddit image was dragged and dropped onto another image:
[image: screen 2]

Screen 3: **Here is what the screen looks like after I create an overlay bitmap with 2 bitmaps combined (notice the reddit image that is now smaller than the original dimensions). NOTE: If I create a temporary bitmap for the reddit image alone (instead of combining it into an overlay with the other bitmap), the reddit icon has correct width and height. This question is only about the dimensions of reddit not about the placement of the icon within the overlay.**

[image: screen 3]

Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".LobbyActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/source_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".5">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flatStanleyImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/reddit" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/postcardImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/target_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".5">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/attractionImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/attraction"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resetButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="reset"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/doneButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="done"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the Java code:

```
public class LobbyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "LobbyActivity";

@BindView(R.id.flatStanleyImage)
protected ImageView flatStanleyImageView;

@BindView(R.id.postcardImage)
protected ImageView postcardImageView;

@BindView(R.id.target_layout)
protected FrameLayout targetLayout;

@BindView(R.id.source_layout)
protected FrameLayout sourceLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lobby);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
            v.startDrag(clipData, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // we are dragging the shadow
            return true;
        }
    };
    flatStanleyImageView.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);

    View.OnDragListener dragListener = new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED. DragEvent.getResult() " + event.getResult());
                    if (!event.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Drag was not successful.");
                        flatStanleyImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    return true;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DROP");

                    FrameLayout draggedImageParentViewLayout = (FrameLayout) flatStanleyImageView.getParent();
                    Log.d(TAG, "draggedImageParentViewLayout: " + draggedImageParentViewLayout.getId());
                    Log.d(TAG, "targetLayout: " + targetLayout.getId());

                    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    float x = event.getX();
                    float y = event.getY();
                    view.setX(x-(view.getWidth()/2));
                    view.setY(y-(view.getWidth()/2));
                    if (draggedImageParentViewLayout != targetLayout) {
                        draggedImageParentViewLayout.removeView(flatStanleyImageView);
                        targetLayout.addView(flatStanleyImageView);
                    }
                    sourceLayout.invalidate();
                    targetLayout.invalidate();
                    return true;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    targetLayout.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
}

@OnClick(R.id.resetButton)
protected void handleResetButtonClick() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Begin handleResetButtonClick");

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);

    Log.d(TAG, "End handleResetButtonClick");
}

@OnClick(R.id.doneButton)
protected void handleDoneButtonClick() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Begin handleDoneButtonClick");

    Bitmap attractionBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.attraction);
    Bitmap flatStanleyBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.reddit);

    Bitmap bitmapOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(attractionBitmap.getWidth(), attractionBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(attractionBitmap, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(flatStanleyBitmap, new Matrix(), null);

    postcardImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapOverlay);
    postcardImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Log.d(TAG, "End handleDoneButtonClick");
}
}
```

Comment: Note: My main concern is why the overlay bitmap gets scaled down when placed on top of another bitmap. If I create a temporary overlay bitmap which contains only the reddit bitmap that is currently being placed on top of the other bitmap, the scaling down does not occur and the image stays the same (correct) size. Note: that both images are in the res/drawable folder. The big image is a .jpg and the reddit (ovelay image) is a .png.

Comment: In `handleDoneButtonClick()`, does `flatStanleyBitmap` have the right dimensions, if you were to examine its `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`?

Comment: the dimensions of `flatStanleyBitmap` inside `handleDoneButtonClick()` are 260x260. Note the reddit.png that is inside of the drawable folder is 65x65 and I am testing this on phone with XXXHDPI density. If I move the reddit.png into drawable-nohdpi, the image still gets scaled although it's much smaller to begin with. Also note, if I set dimensions of the redit `ImageView` to 260x260 in the layout file, the image still appears scaled down after `handleDoneButtonClick()` gets executed

Comment: "the dimensions of flatStanleyBitmap inside handleDoneButtonClick() are 260x260" -- ummm... are those the desired dimensions? If they are, then somehow the image is getting shrunk during `drawBitmap()`, which is baffling. If those are not the desired dimensions, then the problem lies in the `decodeResource()` call. The layout file should have no impact on any of this, as `handleDoneButtonClick()` does not seem to reference anything from the layout (or anything in the UI).

Comment: 260x260 are the desired dimensions. and `drawBitmap()` does not shrink the reddit icon if that's the only image placed in the overlay! it has to do with how the "background" bitmap affects the reddit icon. I hope i don't have to resort to scaling the reddit icon in `drawBitmap()` based on the original size and the other bitmap dimensions.

Comment: "it has to do with how the "background" bitmap affects the reddit icon" -- OK, this may clarify some confusion I had with your original comment. Are you saying that if you comment out the `canvas.drawBitmap(attractionBitmap, new Matrix(), null);` statement, that the Reddit icon is then sized correctly in the output? Have you tried getting rid of the `createBitmap()` call and making your `Canvas` wrap `attractionBitmap` instead? Then you would only need the one `drawBitmap()` call. I am not sure if that helps with this problem, but it would use less heap space.

Comment: Ok glad the problem I am facing is clearer now :) Yes I tried making my `Canvas` wrap the `attractionBitmap` instead of creating a temp overlay. I got `IllegalStateException: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor`

Comment: Use `BitmapFactory.Options.isMutable` in your `decodeResource()` call to get a mutable `Bitmap` back. This requires a `minSdkVersion` of 11 or higher, though, and I don't know if that is acceptable. But I have no idea why the first `drawBitmap()` call would impact the size of the second.

Comment: `BitmapFactory.Options.isMutable` did not solve the icon size issue but it's good to know that option is there! I even tried creating the reddit icon bitmap based on target `RectF`: `RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, 260, 260);` and then `canvas.drawBitmap(flatStanleyBitmap, null, rectf, null);` but it did not help! Thanks a lot for trying to help!

Comment: You might try writing `bitmapOverlay` out as a PNG file and examining it. One possibility is that `bitmapOverlay` is fine, but that it is being squished when you are displaying it. That would not seem to fit the available evidence, but I am grasping at straws now.